# Running JMeter in Command mode is not creating any log for anything under while loop in .jmx file

Tags: jmeter

I have a .jmx file with two thread groups. The first thread group is for data comparison (DB Vs API) and has a JDBC request where I plugin my SQL script and saves it to a tab delimited file. Then I have a while loop under which I have an HTTP request.

Second thread group for negative scenarios validation.

Below is the structure of the .jmx file

```
-- Thread Group Name - FX-Rates
    -- JDBC Request Name - FX-SQL
    -- While loop
        -- HTTP Request - FX Rates - API
-- Thread Group Name - Negative Testing
    -- Error Codes
```

I am running JMeter in **Non GUI** mode using below command.

```
jmeter -n -t "F:\MY DOCUMENTS\PSM\PSM_Automation\bin\Non_GUI_FX_Rates_Validation.jmx" -l "F:\MY DOCUMENTS\PSM\PSM_Automation\log\Non_GUI_FX_Rates_Validation.jtl"
```

I see that it is creating log for each individual sampler i.e; SQL and negative scenarios **but not for anything under while loop**. Below is the log that it created.

**Logfile:**

> timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
>   1492185939615,12140,FX - SQL,200,OK,FX Rates 1-1,text,true,,18549,0,1,1,12017,0,1566
>   1492185951933,0,**Error 400: Invalid Date Format,Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException,Non HTTP response message: Illegal character in query at index 80: https://sys-fxrt-v0.apps.system.pcf.ntrs.com/foreign-exchange-rates?as-of-date=${D_EXCH_RT_EFF}**,Negative Testing - Error Codes 2-1,text,false,,1105,0,1,1,0,0,0
>   1492185951935,190,Error 404: No Account,404,Not Found,Negative Testing - Error Codes 2-1,text,true,,354,232,1,1,189,0,170
>   1492185952127,20,Error 404: Incorrect URL,404,Not Found,Negative Testing - Error Codes 2-1,text,false,,354,241,1,1,19,0,12
>   1492185952147,19,Error 204: No Data ,404,Not Found,Negative Testing - Error Codes 2-1,text,true,,354,260,1,1,19,0,12

Comment: Add a debug sampler and check whether you are seeing valid response for ${D_EXCH_RT_EFF}. Also, make sure that you are using correct method set in the HTTP sampler (GET, POST,PATCH etc). If it is still failing, change the implementation to Java and try again.

Comment: It is executing While loop, but it is failing due to Error 400. Please check my first comment.

Comment: @Naveen : Error 400  is a negative scenario and it is not under the while loop. Also, Method in HTTP Request is GET. Issue is not regarding the failure. When in run the same .jmx file in GUI mode it works but when i execute it in command mode it is not creating log for the HHTP request which is under the while loop

Comment: Please clearly add your test plan snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the *kind of* sampler result is there:

> **Error 400: Invalid Date Format,Non HTTP response code: java.net.URISyntaxException,Non HTTP response message: Illegal
>   character in query at index 80:
>   https://sys-fxrt-v0.apps.system.pcf.ntrs.com/foreign-exchange-rates?as-of-date=${D_EXCH_RT_EFF}**

Obviously that is because the `D_EXCH_RT_EFF` is not set/resolved in your URL.

That's the problem you're gonna debug. 
Obviously.

If you're already doing that (debugging), and run into a problem during it - then describe it please.

And show two things: how you set (initialize) the variable; how you use it, means, literally, show your HTTP sampler (yes, screenshot, at least).

Answer (score 0):

The reasons of not entering the "While Loop" can be in:

1. While condition is returning `false`
2. While condition is wrong
3. If your While Condition depends on a variable coming from `JDBC Request Name - FX-SQL` sampler - double check this variable value using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.

General "good practice" is running your test with 1-2 virtual users in GUI mode and inspect requests and responses details in the View Results Tree listener. Also pay attention to any suspicious entries in *jmeter.log* file. Don't run your JMeter test with the full load until you are totally sure that it is doing what it is supposed to be doing. See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more information on JMeter tests troubleshooting techniques.